# Making the conceptual leap from locales to Grothendieck topologies?

Tags: sheaf-theory, intuition, topos-theory, grothendieck-topology, sites

I find the definition for locales and sheaves on locales to be straightforward, but I'm stumbling over the idea of a Grothendieck topology.  Is there a nice way to see roughly how the latter generalises the former?  And is there a nice way to interpret the idea of a Grothendieck topos in a similar way to the sheaf topos on some locale?  If it's easier to replace "locale" with "topological space" then that works just as well.

Comment: The standard way to make a locale a site is that an object is covered by a collection of subobjects iff that object is the join of the (objects representing the) subobjects. Also, have you yet seen [Lawvere-Tierney topology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere-Tierney+topology)?

Comment: The other basic example of a Grothendieck topos is the category of $G$-sets for a group $G$, which I intuit as being a way that Grothendieck toposes can vary that is completely orthogonal to how locales vary. And those two options essentially cover all possibilities: every Grothendieck topos is (equivalent to) the category of sheaves for a localic groupoid.

Comment: The correct analogy is this: (Grothendieck sites) : (Grothendieck topos) :: (presentation of a frame) : (locale).